# What is the fastest way to jump to a constructor(s) in a class?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I’m using Visual Studio 2010, with Resharper. Many classes in my project are very big and I wonder if there is a shortcut to jump between constructor(s) of my class.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use Resharpers *Goto File Member* which is Alt + \
The constructor seems to be always on top of the list, so you just need to Alt + \ and Enter to go to the constructor of the current class.

Comment: It appears to no longer be on the top of the list for Resharper 9.x, but the shortcut `ctor` works. So, Alt+\, then type "ctor", then enter.

Comment: According to this guide, you can also type `new`:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/05/19/code-navigation-resharper-80-vs-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: None of the suggestions here seem to work with ReSharper 2021.1. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Jazimov https://stackoverflow.com/a/67984111/1016183

Answer (score 5):

With Resharper there is also "blind" way.
Like l.poellabauer said by using Goto File Member which is Alt + \ , But You can type there *'ctor'*, that will display classs constructors with first one selected. So just press Enter or select desired constructor with Up/Down and go navigate to it.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any shortcut for reaching constructors, but if you are instantiating a class with new (e.g. `new A()` ), you can reach to constructor of `A` by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> or selecting "Go to Definition" on `A()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'dont know a shortcut, but resharper has a window called 'File Structure' (you will find under ReSharper -> Windows -> FileStructure'. This window shows all the methods, ... and constuctors have a special icon an most commonly constructors at the top of each class file. Give them a try.

Comment: Constructors are not at the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

With `Resharper 2019.2`:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to show the "members" search box
2. Type "*ctor*"
3. The construcutor(s) will be filtered and selected
4. Select and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Note: This is using the *ReSharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA* keyboard scheme (ReSharper > Options > Environment > Keyboard & Menus > Keyboard Shortcuts)